# Doctrine try to re-add existing entity when added to new entity collection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to configure Doctrine for my project and I am running into some problems when adding an existing entity to a collection(many-to-many relationship).

Here's the first entity:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="formations")
 */
class Formation
{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $id;


.....(others attributes)

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Fsi\Uec\Domaine\Organisme\Organisme",cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinTable(name="formation_organization",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="formation_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="organization_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $organismes;


.....
    public function addOrganisme(Organisme $organisme)
    {
        if(!$this->hasOrganisme($organisme))
            $this->organismes->add($organisme);
    }

    private function hasOrganisme(Organisme $organisme): bool
    {
        return $this->organismes->contains($organisme);
    }
```

The second entity :

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="organizations")
 */
class Organisme
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * @Column(name="active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $actif;
```

Add the entity to collection and saving ($em is doctrine entity manager)

```
$formation = new Formation(....);

$organisme = $em->getRepository(Organisme::class)->find($id)
$formation->addOrganisme($organisme);

$em->persist($formation);
$em->flush();
```

On flush, I get the following error : Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'xxxx' for key 'PRIMARY'

It feels to me like Doctrine is trying to re-add the 'Organisme' entity when it already exists.

Some help with this would be appreciated !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your method  **addOrganisme** to this :

```
public function addOrganisme(Organisme $organisme)
{
    if(!$this->organismes->contains($organisme))
        $this->organismes->add($organisme);
}
```

To be sure that you check if "organismes" has the organisme or not.

Comment: This is exactly what my hasOrganisme function is doing. I already check for this in my addOrganisme.

Comment: Did you try it ?